# How to handle a dynamic number of thread-owned resources

Tags: arrays, multithreading, c++11, stdvector, condition-variable

I have a templated class in which multiple threads have their own copy of variables (buffers, mutexes, condition-variables).

```
template<size_t N> // N = number of threads
class Foo
{
private:
    void thread_job(const int id);
    std::vector<std::thread> threads; // initialized via push_back(std::thread)
    std::string thread_buffer[N];
    std::mutex mu[N];
    std::condition_variable cond[N];
};
```

I understand these variables to be a collection of *separate* objects, so that threads can acquire locks for specific elements without interfering with others:

```
void Foo<N>::thread_job(const int id)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> locker{mu[id]};
    thread_buffer[id].swap(input_buffer);
    cond[id].notify_one();
}
```

Let's say I wanted to move away from defining the number of threads at compile-time and instead store thread-related variables in a dynamic container like a std::vector. Would a thread have to lock the whole container before accessing one of its elements?

If so, do you have suggestions on how to avoid this issue? I can only think of creating arrays with more elements than would conceivably used and sticking to the array approach, e.g.:

```
std::string thread_buffer[64];
std::mutex mu[64];
std::condition_variable cond[64];
```

Answer (score 1):

> Would a thread have to lock the whole container before accessing one
>   of its elements?

No, as long as you can guarantee that another thread does not modify said container at the same time.

Comment: My design cannot guarantee that, it would kill most of the parallelism. So I'm really looking for a dynamic alternative to regular arrays.